# mocking @value annotation of int data type

Tags: java, spring, junit

```
@Component
public class MyHelper {     
    @Value("${max.retry.count:3}")
    private int maxRetryCount;

    @Value("${max.query.count:1000}")
    private int maxQueryCount;
}
```

I am reading the value of a variable from a properties file using @value annotation.
When writing a junit using EasyMock, I'm getting an exception as

```
"nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; 
 nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${max.retry.count:3}".
```

If the data type is changed to String, then it's working fine.
Someone help me on how to mock this.

Comment: Though you can achive the values in properties file using @Value annotation it is always advisable to create a Configuration bean and use `@PropertySource("classpath:root/test.props")` for these kind of tasks. this will help you if you have to pickup these configurations from a remote location.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple ways to achieve that.

**MyHelper managed by a Spring IoC container**

In this case, you would need to add additional annotation above your test spec which create an `ApplicationContext` in order to inject `MyHelper` bean.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyHelperTest { ... }
```

You will also need a `properties` file for test. If you're using Spring Boot, you can simply create an `application.properties` file in the scope of your `test/resources` folder and put the values for those properties right there and they will be picked up.

**MyHelper instantiated manually**

This is the easy one. You simply create a constructor or setters for `maxRetryCount` and `maxQueryCount` and set the values in that manner.

```
public class MyHelperTest {
    private MyHelper myHelper = new MyHelper(5, 6);
}
```

In this case, annotations will be simply ignored since `MyHelper` is not managed by a Spring IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line

```
@Value("${max.query.count:1000}")
```

to

```
@Value("#{new int('${max.query.count:1000}')}")
```